# How to include the fuzzy reasoner with jena for an ontology which has been created in Protege?

Tags: jena, owl, ontology, fuzzy, reasoning

I created an owl ontology with protege and i want to use the jena api or the owl api to reason on my ontology with fuzzy logic. my problem is : does the jena api or the owl api incorporates a kind of reasoning with fuzzy logic directly or not ? if not,  can i query  my ontology with jena api or owl api to extract the useful data (which will be used later in fuzzy reasoning) and simply use a java fuzzy tool / library to apply reasoning ?

Comment: Jena does not work with fuzzy logic. For OWL API. there is FuzzyOWL and FuzzyDl reasoner: http://www.umbertostraccia.it/cs/software/FuzzyOWL/index.html - that said, you have to add the corresponding annotations to the axioms if you want to use this API. Well, everything is mentioned in their docs indeed. Good luck

Comment: @UninformedUser Thank's.